# Android RecyclerView, uses of AdapterObserver for showing empty result view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to develop a `RecyclerView` with the capability for showing an empty view whenever there's no connection or no data. How do i use an AdapterObserver? From my basic point of view, it's complex. I have a `RecyclerView` with the required stuff (adapter, itemdecorator).

Comment: What I do is to put 2 views inside of a RelativeLayout, which are a RecyclerView and a TextView. The TextView is over the RecyclerView (hint: Use centerInParent attribute in both views), and if the RecyclerView is empty I show the TextView indicating that there are no data.

Comment: Agreed with programmer23, you can just bringToFront on the view to determine which one is going to come up on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to reformat your title to be more clear. Second, use this class:

```
public static boolean testConection(Context context){
        boolean HaveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean HaveConnectedMobile = false;
        boolean result;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
        {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        result = HaveConnectedWifi || HaveConnectedMobile;
        return result;
    }
```

Then, use it this way:

```
boolean connready = testConection(this);
        if (connready) {
             // show the RecyclerView
        } else {
             // hide the RecyclerView or show other view for no connection
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: I already use that connection detection method, right now, im adjusting my recyclerview to show information when no results found, also, when its not connected, i have to show a view with thar note in detail

Comment: Exactly! Use a Visibility.VISIBLE or GONE to show and hide views. Remember to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: marked as correct! using Visibility.VISIBLE or GONE, with some fixes to my recyclerview did the trick. thanks!!!